# Share keyboard, mouse, and clipboard

Tags: usb, kvm

I've been using Synergy for many years and I definitely like how it works. But now I need to add a Chromebook to my list of devices and unfortunately Synergy does not support Chrome OS.

I need to share both the (wired) keyboard and mouse, between a Linux server and a Chrome OS client. I am currently using a [USB KVM switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MXXQKGM), but it has a bit of a lag when switching.

I'm looking for a device with a flawless transition between the machines, preferably without the push of a button. I would also like to share the clipboard between the machines.
Is there a keyboard that has the ability to connect to multiple machines and switch between them?